# Subclass not calling overriden parent's interface method

Tags: java, android

I have a custom TimePickerDialog that extends from Android's. This dialog has an interface `OnTimeSetListener` that has to be implemented by its Context or parent Fragment.

**CustomTimePickerDialog.java**

```
public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements
        android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    ...

    private OnTimeSetListener listener;

    public static TimePickerDialog newInstance(int hour, int minutes) {
        TimePickerDialog fragment = new TimePickerDialog();

        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new android.app.TimePickerDialog(getContext(), this, 0, 0, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minutes) {
        listener.onTimeSet(hour, minutes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Object parent = getParentFragment() == null
                ? context
                : getParentFragment();

        if (parent instanceof OnTimeSetListener) {
            listener = ((OnTimeSetListener) parent);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(parent + " must implement OnTimeSetListener");
        }
    }

    public interface OnTimeSetListener {
        void onTimeSet(int hour, int minutes);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to extends this class again to change the `onTimeSet()` behaviour, like this:

**LimitedCustomTimePickerDialog.java**

```
public class LimitedCustomTimePickerDialog extends CustomTimePickerDialog {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minutes) {
        int standardMinutes = minutes < 30 ? 0 : 30;
        super.onTimeSet(timePicker, hour, standardMinutes);
    }

}
```

But it is never called! How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You implemented interface both side so who is calling `onTimeSet`? Just implement where you want to use this method.

Comment: Only the superclass is implementing it, the subclass is overriding its method. `onTimeSet` is being called by the native Android TimePickerDialog, which occurs when the user clicks on the dialog's "OK" button.